# How to check the existence of a user from another microservice

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices

I want to understand the microservice architecture and I have a question like this: I have a microservice for registering and issuing tokens, and a microservice for orders, each of them has its own database. So, when placing an order, I need to somehow check that the user by the passed id really exists.
I thought about api calls  to user microservice, but this is not good idea i think, this will create connectivity between microservices.
There are also message brokers, but they will not work here either, since if the user microservice is busy, then we will not wait long for a response.
Is there any good proposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in a typical microservice architecture you would have one single API called an **API Gateway** that your clients call. That API Gateway is responsible for sequentially calling each of the other APIs that are exposed by your microservices. This way the microservices never call each other.

So in your case, I would expect the client (MVC web site, Angular website, iOS or Android app, Blazor WASM app, desktop app or whatever) would call your Gateway API and the Gateway API would call the Users microservice and ask if the user exists. Then, if the user does exist, the Gateway API would call the Orders microservice to place the order. Then it would return a response to the client.

Comment: Yes, I have an api gateway, but it is only used to validate the custom token before redirecting to the main route.
It uses the Ocelot package, it does not have its own api, only settings for route redirections and token validation. Is this a good approach if the api gateway has a separate api for each request to microservices?

Comment: You could make the client responsible for doing the check that the user exists before making the POST call to create the order...? If you were writing the client yourself, or if you can trust that the authors of the client application(s) will, then that seems reasonable, and you don't need to add more functionality to your API gateway. But, if you can't trust the client to do that check, maybe you need your gateway API to do more than just re-routing the requests. Just my two cents

Comment: @benjamin, do you really have security in mind when thinking about such a solution my brother?

That sounds like making the life of a malicious user easier.

Comment: I'd be happy to learn more from you about the weaknesses of the approach I suggested, and what your approach would be. Always be learning!